# Timeseries issue where I need to add up with another number to get future time in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, data-analysis

I'm new to python and data-analyses and i'm doing a task.

I have a dataframe which has timeseries and time (minutes) as integers  and i want to make calculation where the time and the minutes give another time which will show that the Technician is occupied/unavailable.

Sample of the dataframe:

```
Date_Time           Line    Downtime   Issue    Owner
2020-05-08 18:39:00 T10     32         Reason 1 Technician2
2020-05-08 19:20:00 T10     65         Reason 2 Technician3
2020-05-08 21:13:00 T14     20         Reason 1 Technician1
2020-05-08 21:26:00 T12     12         Reason 4 Technician4
```

I have 16 Technicians in total and they are divided by shifts (1st & 2nd), so I want between 06:00 to 14:00 to have 8 available technicians.

Once an issue occurs in production, then a technician goes to resolve it, so I have 7 technicians available at that time.
In the meantime if another issue occurs while the 1st one is not resolved yet, then I have 6 technicians available.

**The "Downtime" column is represented in Minutes.**

The output i want to have is the following:

```
Date_Time           Line    Downtime   Issue    Owner       Avail. Technicians
2020-05-08 18:39:00 T10     32         Reason 1 Technician2 7
2020-05-08 19:20:00 T10     65         Reason 2 Technician3 7
2020-05-08 21:13:00 T14     20         Reason 1 Technician1 7
2020-05-08 21:26:00 T12     12         Reason 4 Technician4 6
```

Is it possible to achieve such results?

If you have any questions, feel free to ask. I'll try to explain as best as i can.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why are there only 6 available on line 3 (at `21:13:00`)?

Comment: Corrected the error there. Thank you for pointing out.
My goal is, out of the total technician per shift I want to know how much available i have or not have in certain time. The issue started in 21:13 and lasted for 20 minutes - meaning one technician was occupied till 21:33, meanwhile another issue at 21:16 occurs between that time and it occupies one more technician, so i have 6 technicians available between the start and the end of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the `Done_Time` and compare that to `Date_Time`:

```
new_df = (df.assign(Done_time=df.Date_Time + pd.to_timedelta(df.Downtime, unit='min'))
            .set_index('Owner',append=True)['Done_time']
            .unstack('Owner')
            .ffill()
         )

num_busy = (df['Date_Time'].values[:,None] < new_df.values).sum(1)

df['Avail.Tech'] = 8 - num_busy
```

Output:

```
            Date_Time Line  Downtime     Issue        Owner  Avail.Tech
0 2020-05-08 18:39:00  T10        32  Reason 1  Technician2           7
1 2020-05-08 19:20:00  T10        65  Reason 2  Technician3           7
2 2020-05-08 21:13:00  T14        20  Reason 1  Technician1           7
3 2020-05-08 21:26:00  T12        12  Reason 4  Technician4           6
```